# copy libs into web archieve

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I have an eclipse project in which dependent jars are in a separate folder called libs.
Is there a way in eclipse to configure all the jars in lib folder to be copied into webarchieve's lib folder automatically when I export the war file from eclipse or debug it on server?
I am using tomcat 7 as server runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just go to the 
`project properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Archives`
Any archive that you add this way to dynamic web project would be copied to WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Does that mean that I have to do this everytime I add new jars in the build path?

Comment: I think that you have to manually define everything that goes into your war. However, if you look carefully in `Deployment Assembly -> Add` menu there are also other options such as **Java Build Path Entries** (from there you can add all the libs in one go), or you can define **Fileset** from where all the libs will be copied automatically. Also, if the libs on your build path are in the same project, it makes sense to just move them to WEB-INF/lib.